# Typo in description of "established user"

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, privileges

> User hover cards allow you to show off your awesome to other users in our network.

(from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user).)

A noun ("reputation"?) should come after "awesome".

Comment: The "awesome" of the person **is** the noun. Like one's flair or style or gravitas, some people have awesome. People like playing with language on the internet.

Comment: See also [this meta.SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105297/established-user-privilege-page-typo).

Comment: As an ESL teacher, I'm used to words being stretched, but this was too much of a stretch. As someone remarked elsewhere, this went against the professionalism that this suite of sites is meant to convey. (-We're talking about the site framework material - whismy in comments (definitely), answers (somewhat), and even questions (a little bit) is another thing.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a joke moreso than an actual typographical error. It's using "awesome" as a noun, technically meaning "awesomeness" but cut short, well, I guess that's supposed to be "awesome".

A revised (and more in-depth) description is currently present on [Meta Stack Overflow's privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) and will be rolled out to other sites, including this one, eventually.

Comment: Huh, I see the `&nbsp;` trick's now documented...

Comment: Thanks. I've up-voted and accepted your answer.

Comment: @Mike Heh, I was going to mark it as status-completed once the change was passed over but I guess that's already been tagged. It doesn't look like the actual change has been pushed to this site but I assume it's right on its way.